# What is the use of super(ClassName,self)._init_()

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def bar(self):
        self.bar1_out = self.x + 5
        self.bar2_out = self.x + 1
        return (self.bar1_out,self.bar2_out)
    def qux(self,myvalue = None):
        first, second = myvalue or self.bar()
        return first + 3, second + 6

def main():
    """docstring for main"""
    f = Foo(5)

    mbr_out1, mbr_out2 = f.bar()
    print mbr_out1, "\t", mbr_out2

    mqx_out1, mqx_out2 = f.qux()
    print mqx_out1, "\t", mqx_out2

    qout1, qout2 = f.qux((1))
    print qout1, "\t", qout2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I saw some implementation that suggest using `super`

```
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(Foo,self).__init__()
        self.x = x
    def bar(self)
        #etc.
```

My questions are:

1. What's the use of `super(Foo,self).__init__()`
2. How does it differ from `self.x=x`
3. How can I make my code top above produce the same result by using `super()`

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does it differ from `self.x=x`?

`super()` is only useful if you subclass:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(x)
        self.initial_status = False
```

is better than setting `self.x = x` in `Bar`'s `__init__`.

The difference is that `Bar` doesn't need to care about the implementation of `Foo`.

If you choose to change `Foo` in a way which sets `self.x = 2 * x`, then you won't have to change `Bar` as well (which might even sit in a difference file - failure to see this is almost guaranteed).

In your example, there is no point to use `super()` as you don't subclass.

Comment: Thanks. How can I reimplement my initial code with `super` and see the effect of it?

Comment: @neversaint I just saw that you don't subclass anything... I'll rewrite my answer.